# Why httpserver won't on separate thread with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, httpserver

First of all, I'm relatively new to python so in case I'm doing something incredibly stupid please let me know.

I have this desktop app to be run on a raspberyy pi and developed with python and tkinter for the GUI and due to new requirements in the project, it needs to be able to receive a command remotely to do some action.

To achieve this i wanted to add a http server to the project

In my main script i have this:

```
from tkinter import *  
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import threading

# Create GUI app and define general properties
window = Tk()
window.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
window.config(cursor="none")

winWidth = int(window.winfo_screenwidth() * 1)
winHeight = int(window.winfo_screenheight() * 1)

window.geometry(f"{winWidth}x{winHeight}")

class HttpHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>https://pythonbasics.org</title></head>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>Request: %s</p>" % self.path, "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<body>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>This is an example web server.</p>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>", "utf-8"))

 
#Start HTTP Server
webServer = HTTPServer(('localhost', 9080), HttpHandler)
print('running http server on port: ', 9080)
threading.Thread(target=webServer.serve_forever, daemon=True) 
    
window.mainloop()
```

Right now the code is very basic just to get it running but the idea was to later on, do an IO operation on a http request. For example /api/lights/on would trigger a GPIO.

I had to use threading.Thread because otherwise the script would block on webServer.serve_forever()

By using threading it no longer blocks and shows the GUI properly. Also with a 'netstat -lnt' I can tell that the http server is listening on the specified port.

When I open the browser on http://127.0.0.1:9080/ the browser never gets a response.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please replace the syntax error and incomprehensible `{…}` in your question with __actual code__ that makes your content in your question a [mre]. Anyone must be able to copy/paste the code in your question into a file and _without adding anything_ run it to see the ame problem yu do.

Comment: did you run it in console to see if it display error message?

Comment: first you could better organize code - all classes and function put directly after imports - it means before `window = Tk()`. See more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: when I run it then it shows error message - you forgot to impor `threading` and server can't run

Comment: About the import, it was present in my code when i edited the post i just forgot to copy that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found two mistakes

1. you forgot import `threading` so it gives error message

   ```
   import threading
   ```
2. you created thread but you forgot to start it

   ```
   t = threading.Thread(target=webServer.serve_forever, daemon=True)
   t.start()
   ```

---

**BTW:**

You could better organize code.
See: [PEP 8 --Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.pythn.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

# --- classes ---

class HttpHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>https://pythonbasics.org</title></head>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>Request: %s</p>" % self.path, "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<body>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>This is an example web server.</p>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>", "utf-8"))

# --- functions ---

# empty

# --- main ---

webServer = HTTPServer(('localhost', 9080), HttpHandler)
print('running http server: http://localhost:9080')  # some consoles will display URL as clickable so it is easier to run browser
t = threading.Thread(target=webServer.serve_forever, daemon=True)
t.start()

window = tk.Tk()

#window.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
window.config(cursor="none")

#winWidth = int(window.winfo_screenwidth() * 1)
#winHeight = int(window.winfo_screenheight() * 1)
#window.geometry(f"{winWidth}x{winHeight}")
    
window.mainloop()
```

---

I only wondering if using `http.server` is good idea. If you want to access by web page then it can be simpler to create pages with `Flask`. If you want to send small commands then maybe it would be simpler use server [MQTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT)
instead of `HTTP`. Some `IoT` devices my already use `MQTT`

---

Other problem can make communications between threads. Tkinter doesn't like to run in subthreads so you can't access widget directly in thread with server and it will need queue to send values to main thread and tkinter will need `after(millisecond, function)` to check queue periodically to get command.

---

**EDIT:**

Version which uses `queue` to send information from `http server` to `tkinter` and it displays it in widget `Text`

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import queue

# --- classes ---

class HttpHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>https://pythonbasics.org</title></head>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>Request: %s</p>" % self.path, "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<body>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>This is an example web server.</p>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>", "utf-8"))

        q.put("Request: %s" % self.path)  # put in `queue`
        
# --- functions ---

def check_queue():
    if not q.empty():
        text.insert('end', q.get()+'\n') # get from `queue` and put in `Text`
    window.after(100, check_queue)  # check again after 100ms
    
# --- main ---

q = queue.Queue()

webServer = HTTPServer(('localhost', 9080), HttpHandler)
print('running http server: http://localhost:9080')  # some consoles will display URL as clickable so it is easier to run browser
t = threading.Thread(target=webServer.serve_forever, daemon=True)
t.start()

window = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(window)
text.pack()

check_queue()

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

The same with `Flask`. It can get data: args, json, form, files, etc.

```
import queue
import threading
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

# --- classes ---

    
# --- functions ---

app = Flask(__name__)

#@app.route('/')
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def index(path):

    print('path:', path)
    print(f'Request: {request.method} {request.url}')
    print('args:', request.args)
    print('form:', request.form)
    print('data:', request.data)
    print('json:', request.json)
    print('files:', request.files)
    
    q.put(f'Request: {request.method} {request.url}')  # put in `queue`

    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>https://pythonbasics.org</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Request: {{ request.method }} {{ request.url }}</p>
<p>This is an example web server.</p>
</body>
</html>''', request=request)

def check_queue():
    if not q.empty():
        text.insert('end', q.get()+'\n') # get from `queue` and put in `Text`
    window.after(100, check_queue)  # check again after 100ms
    
# --- main ---

q = queue.Queue()

print('running http server: http://localhost:9080')  # some consoles will display URL as clickable so it is easier to run browser
t = threading.Thread(target=app.run, args=('localhost', 9080), daemon=True)
t.start()

window = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(window)
text.pack()

check_queue()

window.mainloop()
```

But now question is: why to use `tkinter` if you may do all in `flask`

Comment: Thank you for the incredily detailed answer. It turned out to be the missing t.start() that was causing the issue.
Just to clarify a bit further the idea here is not to provide a web page to the client but provide an api to a 3rd party software to control the application (so content-type changes to application/json and i would send them a json response). In this particular case it is to open a door so there is no interaction with tkinter widgets just the raspberry GPIO's. I've tested it and it seems to be  working but i'll only be sure on monday when i can wire some leds into it.

Comment: Also about the alternative that you provided, I had no idea it we could use queues with tkinter, I will study your examples because it can useful in the future. Thank you very much.

Comment: yes, for API with JSON  you don't need `Flask`. `http.server` seems better idea - smaller then `Flask` and simpler then pure `socket`. I uses raspberry to detect motion in garden and observe animals/hedgehogs at night and I use `MQTT` to send message to server at home (another raspberry). And later other computers (notebooks) uses `MQTT` to get this message from server.